# How do I set up a Single Application Kiosk in Ubuntu 18.04 (custom xsession .desktop)?

Tags: 18.04, plex, kodi, kiosk, appimage

Does anyone know how to run Ubuntu 18.04 in Single-Application, or Kiosk mode, with direct boot to Application, without logging in or anything?

I want to start Plex-Media-Player (like Kodi) directly on boot (Plex.AppImage), without starting a Desktop.

All tutorials I could find are for 12.04/14.04.

Comment: Found this with a quick search.

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/07/create-ubuntu-kiosk

Comment: Thanks. But thats from 2014 and not working anymore.

Comment: Here is a newer answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391627/single-application-visible-not-a-web-kiosk