# Single application visible (not a web kiosk)?

Tags: boot, budgie, kiosk

I'm looking to make a dedicated writing machine. Essentially what I want is a fullscreen text editor like focuswriter with dropbox running so I can sync my writing file with other computers.

I'm not a linux power user—I've gone down a few paths of trying to start with a terminal-based linux distro and add what I need, but I keep on hitting dead ends.

So, I have a dell latitude laptop, ubuntu (budgie) installed, dropbox installed, my writing program installed.

How can I now make it so that the writing program starts up automatically on boot and have nothing else accessible?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your choices might be:

1. [Cage](https://github.com/Hjdskes/cage), a [Wayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/)-based compositor designed to run a single
   application. You might be able to make it run dropbox in background
   with a shell script.
2. [`xinit`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinit), a command do launch another X
   windowing server instance. Best used in a tty like so: `xinit office-command $* -- :0 vt$XDG_VTNR`. You can also write a
   [~/.xinitrc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinit#xinitrc) file that specifies commands you want to autorun,
   including dropbox.
3. [Sway](https://swaywm.org/) with [Waybar](https://github.com/Alexays/Waybar). It has quite a bit of
   a learning curve, but it has excellent tray support, and can make
   any kind of window fullscreen at will with `Win + F`. It's also rather user-friendly, for a tiling WM.

If you choose `xinit` or Cage, you might want to look at [`stalonetray`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/stalonetray), as a tray is required and optimal for Dropbox.

As for the autostart bit, run `sudoedit /usr/share/xsessions/write-and-dropbox.desktop`. An editor will pop up, and you should enter something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Write Mode
Comment=Start Office and Dropbox in stalonetray
Exec=/usr/local/bin/writemode-init
TryExec=/usr/local/bin/writemode-init
Type=Application
```

Save, then create the aforementioned file with `sudoedit /usr/local/bin/writemode-init` and add something like this (depends on what you chose as a solution):

```
#!/bin/sh
# ^^^ define the interpreter
cage 'sh -c "your-office-app &; stalonetray &; sleep 1; dropbox &;"'
```

Save it too, then make it executable with `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/writemode-init`. Reboot, and now you should be able to select and use "Write Mode" (or whaever you call it) from your login screen. It is recommended to reboot beforehand and test the newly added `writemode-init` command in a TTY to make sure it works as intended.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you! Cage sounds like it might be a little outside of my abilities. If I were to go the xinit route, would the directions be essentially the same?

Comment: As this is not an actual solution it should have been made as a comment.

Comment: @Tom, yes, but you probably would like to make the writemode-init script firs `xinit &` the tray then actually launch Dropbox and your office application.

Comment: @David - in which way is this post not a solution? Also, comments do not support long texts, try to paste my post in a comment and you'll see why.

Comment: @SavchenkoDmitriy Are you available for some help with this answer? I'd be happy if you could contact me (see https://slhck.info/contact/). Thanks!

Comment: @slhck, I've sent you a friend request on Discord, and I'm happy to help. Fell free to accept and DM me there