# Is it possible to boot a Pyglet script as the desktop environment

Tags: python3, opengl

I'd like to create a media center similar to Kodi in Pyglet. Was wondering if it'd be possible to boot into my Pyglet script as the primary DE.

For those wanting more details, I plan to make it a streaming box, capable of playing anything you find on Google Video search.

Comment: When I login at the *greeter* or DM, I can choose what session I'll use. On my install here (*you didn't provide release details so I'm using my own noble system*) I have options which include multiple DEsktop choices (that I have installed), plus some WM (*window managers*) that will not load a desktop... You don't have to have a session that contains a DE itself.. for older hardware having lighter options is actually beneficial. Have you explored setting up a session for your *unstated* DM  (`/usr/share/xsessions`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch google-chrome/chromium application shortcut in fullscreen/kiosk mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358898/how-to-launch-google-chrome-chromium-application-shortcut-in-fullscreen-kiosk-mo)

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/q/1391627/158442